# if $f(0)=0,f^{'}(0)=0, \int_1^2f(x)dx=6\int_0^1f(x)dx$, is there is one point $x_0$ in (0,2) such that $f^{(3)}(x_0)=0$?

Tags: calculus

I encountered some questions when I'm doing this exercise:
$f(0)=0,f^{'}(0)=0,\int_1^2f(x)dx=6\int_0^1f(x)dx,$ than there is a point $x_0\in(0,2)$ such that $f^{(3)}(x_0)=0$
I noticed that $6=3!$, but I cannot see what's the key to this question.

Comment: Search for similar problems.

Comment: could you tell me where are the similar problems?

Comment: Search keywords in the search bar. Or use Approach0: https://approach0.xyz/search/

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false.

Let $F$ denote an antiderivative of $f.$ Then
$$F(2)-F(1)=6[F(1)-F(0)]$$ which is equivalent to
$$7F(1)=F(2)+6F(0)$$
Other two conditions take the form $F'(0)=F''(0)=0.$
The function $F(x)=x^4-9x^3$ satisfies all three assumptions. We have $$f^{(3)}(x)=F^{(4)}(x)=4!$$